# Can't access routers login form page

Tags: router, ip

I am connected to my dorm's internet via WiFi and when I enter the default gateway address from cmd which is 172.16.128.1, I get "This site can't be reached".
I understand there is probably a customized username and pw of the router but shouldn't I get a login menu instead of "This site can't be reached"?

Comment: It's probably MAC restricted, so it can only be accessed by authorized users.

Comment: Have you contacted your school IT support? That is what you need to do. We cannot know what your school might do.

Comment: Why do you expect (or need) to access your dorm's router's configuration?

Comment: Where do you enter it? in your browser? if the web access is disabled (for you or in general) you won't be able to connect. Can you ping it? What do you want to achieve by accessing the router, maybe there is a work around.

Answer (score 1):

You're not dealing with a home router , so there's no reason to expect the institution's router would behave like one. Showing a login form to unauthorized IP/MAC connections could possibly enable a brute-force attack.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple but effective security method to prevent fly-by attacks… & students who think they might want to change parameters to their own benefit ;)

Admin access to the router is disabled over wifi.

You can only connect to it over Ethernet. No way to brute-force into that. It doesn't need to be MAC restricted, it's simply "off". You can't reach it because it's just not there. I use exactly the same method here.

After comments…
Just because you can only connect to it over Ethernet doesn't mean that simply connecting to the IP address on port 80 is going to get you in. First you will need to know the correct port. No-one is ever going to use 80 on a secured gateway/UTM structure, nor are they going to have anything automatically redirect to the correct port.

You don't think they're going to make this easy, do you? You're not authorised to get into it. It's simpler to prevent all student access than to leave open a free-for-all amateur hacker contest. They've probably locked out all access unless from a specified IP range, which the tiered DHCP server is not ever going to hand to you. You're logged as 'student' & are never going to get logged as 'admin' anywhere on the campus.

They could be using MAC address white-lists - though it's as easy to use predetermined white-listing long before anyone gets anywhere near an area they're not allowed to be in. It doesn't really matter which method they use.

I've never been ermm… 'lucky' enough to work IT on a student campus, but I bet they have a fun time keeping the doors not just locked but well-hidden, because every one of their 3,000 students thinks they *need* access to make their own changes.

Comment: Nope, I can't connect to it over ethernet either.

Comment: @Roshin - why do you want to? You have been asked, but have failed to reply.

Comment: You don't think they're going to make this easy, do you? You're not authorised to get into it. It's simpler to prevent all student access than to leave open a free-for-all amateur hacker contest. They've probably locked out all access unless from a specified IP range, which the tiered DHCP server is not ever going to hand to you. You're logged as 'student' & are never going to get logged as 'admin' anywhere on the campus.

Comment: I don't want to access routers admin page (obv I couldn't do that since i don't have customized pw and username). I want to access routers login form page (my question has been changed by mod). I want to know why I'm not able to access login form page and how it is protected out of curiosity. Is it MAC restricted in routers admin page settings?

Comment: 'routers login form' you mean the portal? That's an entirely different question, no-one could guess from what you actually posted.  If a portal is not responding correctly you'll have to ask your IT department… because, as you've noted, you can't get into it if you're not IT.

Comment: I don't know why you're accusing me of trying to "hack" the network and make the changes by just searching default gateway address. I am cruious about how exactly is login page protected and why it can't be reached. (That's also what I asked in my original question). Never stated that I think it would be possible to enter router settings.

Comment: A router's "login page" is not the same thing as a "captive portal". It is very unclear now what you are actually trying to do. You need to edit your question to clarify.

Comment: By router login form page i mean page with inputs for username and password, the page you would get after searching gateway address. Not captive portal but the page that allows you to login to routers admin page (again I know it's not possible to enter admin page nor am i trying). All i want to know is why i can't see that router login form page. Is it because it's protected by MAC address restriction inside router settings?

Comment: MAC address protection would be unlikely, but possible. See the edits to my answer above for many of the reasons you are never going to see it. It's easier to prevent people ever getting to the page than it is to have to fight a myriad failed logins every day.